# Audio file recorded using MicrophoneRecorder in windows phone 8 not playing on iPhone

Tags: ios, audio, windows-phone-8, microphone, recording

I am developing a windows phone 8 app, in which I am using MicrophoneRecorder class to record a sound file in .m4a format & playing it successfully. I used to upload that file to server & save it there.
When I downloaded the file it is showing that the file is in .m4a format. 
Problem is occurring when the same file is downloaded in iPhone, it is not playing though it is a .m4a file & iPhone supports it.

Can anyone help or suggest where I am going wrong.

Comment: What are you using to play this file on iOS? Please provide some code

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the configurations that iphone (iOS) support it and it is as follows:

Audio Codec: AAC 
Audio Bitrate: from 32 to 320
Sample Rate: from 8000 to 48000

Comment: But how can I get this in Windows phone.